# How do i configure using a custom ServiceHostFactory with an Ajax Enabled WCF service

Tags: ajax, wcf

I am working on a Ajax enabled WCF service, and I need to use a custom ServiceHostFactory.
I found several posts like [this one](http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2008/02/21/custom-servicehostfactory-for-wcf-and-iis.aspx)

However even though i have added the factory parameter to the svc file (like you see below) the factory is never called:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Factory="CustomHostFactory" Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="mysite.ScriptingService.BasketScriptingService" CodeBehind="BasketScriptingService.svc.cs" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turnes out it was another problem that prevented the factory from being called. So it actually already worked :)